# Given a large, multiloop circuit with resistors and batteries and I'm not sure how to simplify it. (When NOT to combine resistors?)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

So here's the circuit, and the question is looking for current i:
[image]

All resistors are 2 ohms and the batteries are 5 volts. I'm trying to apply the resistance combination Kurchov rules to make this easier before I start handling the loops, but I'm not sure how the presence of batteries and other pieces of circuitry or the presence of other loops affect those rules. Can I combine Resistors across batteries? Is there some way to combine batteries? And is there a way I can simplify this circuit to be one battery and one resistor?

Comment: Start simplifying where possible, and see where that gets you. Then simplify again. But I'm not going to do you homework for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Effective resistance of a weird looking electric circuit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/337924)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the batteries are directly linked together, which allows you to easily find the voltage across different wires. For this you could start at the wire above the resistor, for which you have to determine the current, and work your way through the circuit. The lower end is not directly connected to a battery, so you do have to simplify some of the resistors, but not all.